# Books on iPad no longer downloading purchased books

Tags: ipad, icloud, books, ipados

I have 1,076 iBooks purchased from the iStore in my iCloud. I have, starting just this holiday morning, the ability to read 0 iBooks on my iPad in the Books app. Is there any other app which I can download that can access iBooks?

What happens is that I click on a book to download it and it informs me instantaneously that the book will be found in my library when it is done downloading. Then, as the screen shows a large version of the book with a light grey progress bar beneath it, either nothing happens or approx. 5% of the bar goes dark gray (in another view, a tiny bit of the “downloading indicator” circle turns dark. That is all. No books have yet to become available in My Library or anywhere else.

After consulting with Apple Support I have tried the following things to remedy this problem:

- App was uninstalled and reinstalled
- iPad was shut down and restarted
- the newest update was installed
- the Apple systems web page was consulted to see if the Books problem was Apple’s problem (which it was not)
- I logged out and back in to Books
- the date/time was confirmed as correct
- my wi-fi was tested and works fine

That is all I can think if right now. I read every day for 4 or 5 hours on my iPad. It is a huge part of my life and I was reading just last night. Now not one of any of the 10s of random books I tried to download will. Can anyone help?

If there is no other app that will download them and this is somehow a hardware problem that cannot be solved, can they be read by another 'mobile' device as I cannot see myself spending 3 hours reading from a 2015 MacBook screen all day. If it helps I also have a kindle and Samsung tablet.